# Android Animation Slide Activity Down

Tags: java, android, xml, animation

I have searched but have not found an answer. I need an XML animation where it takes an activity in the middle of the screen and slides it down and out of view.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="100%p" android:duration="600"/>
</set>
```

this is the animation XML itself, i presume you know how to handle the activity transitions

Comment: Yes thats all I needed, I know hoe to deal with it

Comment: ok great, if it works for you be sure to accept this as the answer with the check mark on the left! :)